# converting timestamp to MM DD,YYYY and vice versa with out any npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written below microservice to convert unix timestamp to a format like `Dec 01,2017` and vice versa and deployed here [timestamp](https://timestamp-microservoce.glitch.me/12444332223332)

Is their any better way to do this with out third party NPM

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');


app.route('/:date')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        // res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
        var unix = null,
            naturaldate = null;
        //console.log(parseInt(timestamp),timestamp)
        let timestamp = req.params.date;
        if (!isNaN(timestamp)) {
            let parsetime = new Date(parseInt(timestamp))
            console.log(parsetime);
            if (parsetime == 'Invalid Date') {
                console.log("got invalid date")
                send_response(null, null, res);
            }
            let parsenaturaldate = parsetime.toDateString().split(" ").slice(1);
            let year = parsenaturaldate.splice(2, 0, ',');
            year = parsenaturaldate.splice(1, 0, ' ')
            naturaldate = parsenaturaldate.join("")
            console.log(naturaldate)
            unix = parseInt(timestamp)
            send_response(unix, naturaldate, res);
        } else {
            unix = Date.parse(timestamp);

            if (!isNaN(unix))
                naturaldate = timestamp
            else
                send_response(null, null, res);
            send_response(unix, naturaldate, res);
        }
    })

function send_response(unix, naturaldate, res) {
    console.log(unix, naturaldate)
    res.json({
        "unix": unix,
        "natural": naturaldate
    })
}

app.listen(8083 || process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log("server is listening")
})
```

Comment: What time in a day is used for the timestamp? which timezone?

Comment: Maybe you want `date.toISOString().replace(/^(....)-(..)-(..).*$/, '$2 $3,$1')`?

Comment: i want to convert a timestamp to MM DD ,YYYY with out npm.Ex- timestamp 1512086400000 should show to its value Dec 01,2017 .Currently i am doing like new Date(1512086400000 ) which return Fri Dec 01 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) ,i am using splice ,join function to made this to Dec 01,2017 format ,So any other better way to do this ?@tsh

Comment: date.toISOString().replace(/^(....)-(..)-(..).*$/, '$2 $3,$1') returning 12 01,2017 not like dec 01,2017

Comment: you are talking about `MMM DD,YYYY` not `MM DD,YYYY`. Try `date.toString().replace(/\S* (\S*) (\S*) (\S*) .*/, '$1 $2,$3')`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should do roughly what you want. If you need to change the format of the months you can just edit the `monthNames` array.

```js
var date = new Date(2017,11,1);
var monthNames = [
  "jan", "feb", "mar",
  "apr", "may", "jun", "jul",
  "aug", "sep", "oct",
  "nov", "dec"
];

var day = date.getDate();
var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();

day = day < 10 ? "0" + day.toString() : day.toString();

var result = monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + day + ',' + year;
console.log(result);
```

To reverse the process you will need to split the string into it's parts, find the index of the month name in the array and then create a new `Date` from those parts.